# Capture optional Group

Tags: regex, regex-group

I want to capture the values of some keys which may be optional, specifically consider the string below

```
@Foo1:dog|a=5|b=6|c=10|d=12|e=2
@Foo2:cat|a=12|c=10|d=11|e=123
@Foo1:bat|a=213123|b=10
@Foo3:pet|c=346
```

Now I want to capture the strings between @ and :, : and |, and the value of keys b, d which may be optional. 
I should the following captured

```
Foo1, dog, 6, 12
Foo2, cat, 11
Foo1, bat, 10
Foo3, pet
```

I am using this regex
`^@(\w+):(\w+).*(?:b=(\d+)).*(?:d=(\d+))` but it only works when both b and d are present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^@(\w+):(\w+)(?:.*?\|b=(\d+))?(?:.*?\|d=(\d+))?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wsmc5A/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `@` - a `@` char
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `:` - a colon
- `(\w+)` - Group 2: one or more word chars
- `(?:.*?\|b=(\d+))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, then `|b=` and then capturing 1+ digits into Group 3
- `(?:.*?\|d=(\d+))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, then `|d=` and then capturing 1+ digits into Group 4